# SQL: A column in a subquery does not appear

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a query in MySQL 5.7:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT (@rowNum:=@rowNum+1) AS rowNo,t.* FROM table_target t,(SELECT (@rowNum :=0)) AS b 
WHERE p_d = '2020-11-08' 
ORDER BY kills DESC
) t
WHERE t.uid= '8888'
```

Running this query, there is no exception but column B disappears and if using `select b from` in the outter query, it returns `unknown column` exception.

I have 2 questions:

1. Why the `(SELECT (@rowNum :=0))` does not appear?
2. Is the `(@rowNum:=@rowNum+1)` equivelent to `row_number() over ()` in Oracle? If so, how to understand it...

Thanks for your help in advance.

In addition, I just found if I put the `(SELECT (@rowNum :=0) )` in the left:

```
...
SELECT (SELECT (@rowNum :=0) ) AS b, (@rowNum:=@rowNum+1) AS rowNo , t.* FROM table_target t
...
```

Then the row number column does not increase any more, why could this happen?

Comment: Which column B you are talking about. is it a part of table_target? Please add more clarity in the question

Comment: Hi @AkhileshMishra Thanks for your reply. Column B indicates `(SELECT (@rowNum :=0))`, I just edit the question so that the column name becomes more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have asked 3 questions here:

**Question 1: Why the (SELECT (@rowNum :=0)) does not appear?**

**Answer**: You have used `(SELECT (@rowNum :=0)) as B` as a table joining it  but not calling it in column list after `select`. That's why it is not showing it in output. You have called it as `(@rowNum:=@rowNum+1)` which is showing the value after increment means starting from `1`.

**Question 2: Is the (@rowNum:=@rowNum+1) equivalent to row_number() over () in Oracle? If so, how to understand it**

**Answer:** Yes, it is equivalent. `MySql 8.0 and above` also support this (known as window function). It works as:

- At the time of initialization of the query `(SELECT (@rowNum :=0))` variable `@rowNum` will be initialized with value `0`.
- When we are calling `(@rowNum:=@rowNum+1)` in select then it will add 1 in `@rowNum` and assign it to itself for every row returned by select query.
  This is how it will print the row number.

**Question 3: if I put the (SELECT (@rowNum :=0) ) in the left:**

**Answer:** If you put the `(SELECT (@rowNum :=0) )` as field list after `select` then it will initialize the value of `@rownum` to `0` in every row returned by select. This is why you will not get incremented value.

Answer (score 1):

The column "disappears" because the value is `NULL`.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in the `SELECT`, the initialization might not work.

Second, you code does not do what you intend, even if that worked, because variables may not respect the `ORDER BY`.  I think you intend:

```
select k.*
from (select (@rownum := @rownumn + 1) as rownum, k.*
      from (select k.*
            from kills k
            where k.p_d = '2020-11-08'
            order by kills desc
           ) k cross join
           (select @rownum := 0) params
      ) k
where t.uid = '8888';
```

There are probably better ways to do what you want.  But your question is specifically about variables and MySQL 5.7.